# Scrape info from leaflet map

Tags: python, leaflet, scrape

I'm trying to scrape the information used to make the leaflet map (longitude, latitude, bussiness name, etc.) from this page https://semananacion.com.ar/semananacion/sn-gastronomia with python, but request response seems to be encrypted. Any ideas on how can i get the info?

I tried to emulate the request but didn't work cause response seems to be encrypted. I'm trying to recopile information in a table.

Comment: *seems to be encrypted* -- What makes you think so?  Are you sure it's not just an image that you are treating as text?